# Rails Include Active Record and inherit from another Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a project which connects a government Data Api to Podio. I need access to Active Record in a model which already inherits from a Podio::Item. Is there a way to include ActiveRecord in this model?

```
class LdBase < Podio::Item
  # Include Active::Record


end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The model is pulling information from the govkit api. I then want to check if this information has been pushed up to podio by checking it against my database. If the primary key isn't in my database I want to push it up to podio. I need to inheret from Podio::Item in order to have the push upto podio methods.

Comment: I know I can include ActiveModel, but that seems only to be for ActiveRecord without the db connection. I could also write custom SQL, b/c the methods will be pretty simply.

Comment: If this is a poor questions, please let me know.

Comment: Most likely you do not want to have those two models to be mixed together. If I were you I would create a separate AR model, and implement a method which will return Podio::Item.